# MeteorJS: How to get clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I'm trying to get the clicked element so that I can add class. Does Meteor provides any way to get the current element like jQuery $ (this)

```
Template.retraining.events({
    'click .myclass': function (event) {
        //Get the clicked element like $(this) in jQuery
        $().addClass('existing-col');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the element on which the event occurred, use `event` object.

```
event.target
```

As you've jQuery included, you can wrap the element in jQuery to use jQuery methods on it.

```
$(event.target)
```

You can see this in [Meteor Tutorial](https://github.com/meteor/simple-todos/commit/7a1ace1482bbdd5ce38aa5db28ecb20ce0e12863#diff-99b63e4ea71d2f7c854d07e78d18f79fR17)

[image: event.target]

Answer (score 1):

From this you can get textbox value with one button click event.

Try this:

```
Template.retraining.events({
'click .myclass':function(e,t){
 var val = t.find(".classname").value;
}
```