# Get ID of the clicked element

Tags: jquery, meteor

How to get id from `html()`,

```
$('#example1 tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
    var id = $(this).html();

    alert(id);
});
```

the result is alert `undefined`?

The program run at MeteorJS framework.

Comment: You want to get the ID of clicked `<td>`.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [MeteorJS: How to get clicked element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35194509/meteorjs-how-to-get-clicked-element)

Comment: Use `$(this).attr('id')`.

Comment: `$(this).attr('id')`?

Comment: Is event fired? Are you getting the `alert`?

Comment: Can you show the html template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#example1 tbody tr').each(function(){
   $(this).find("td").each(function(){
     $(this).on( 'click', function () {
      var id  = $(this).attr("id");
      alert(id);
   });
  });
});
```

[Try this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9f8kv1rk/)

Comment: you asked for the id of td right, you want id of input tag??

Comment: I think you can paste any fiddle for it

Comment: Just check out this fiddle added

Answer (score 0):

In Meteor you generally shouldn't use plain jQuery events. Use template events instead. Also, it's a good practice to use `data-action` parameter for attaching events instead of ids and classes:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  'click [data-action~=alert]': function(e, t) {
    var id = $(e.currentTarget).attr('id');
    alert(id);
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#example1 td', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id);
});
```